# Using ddply inside function (non-standard evaluation)

Tags: r, function, dplyr, plyr, evaluation

I am using `ddply` (from the `plyr` package in `R`) inside a wrap function. I want to summarize my dataset based on the value of a variable. However, the wrap function has to define for which variable I want summarize.

Without a wrap function, I can take the following approach:

```
require(plyr)

# Create sample dataframe:
sample_df <- data.frame(a = rep(1:3, 2), b = rep(3:1, 2), c = rep(c("a", "b"), 3))

sample_df
  a b c
1 1 3 a
2 2 2 b
3 3 1 a
4 1 3 b
5 2 2 a
6 3 1 b

# Use ddply to summarize the dataframe:
ddply(sample_df, .(a), summarize, mean = mean(b), var = var(b))
  a mean var
1 1    3   0
2 2    2   0
3 3    1   0
```

However, using a wrap function, I don't get the same results:

```
sumfun <- function(df, v) { # summarize a given dataframe by a given variable, 
  d <- ddply(df, .(v), summarize, mean = mean(b), var = var(b))
  return(d)
}

# Output using the function:
sumfun(sample_df, "a")
  v mean var
1 a    3  NA
```

Why does the behavior of `ddply` differ when using it in a function? I have tried using `substitute(v)` and `eval(substitute(v))` inside the function, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: just change to `d <- ddply(df, .(get(v)), summarize, mean = mean(b), var = var(b))` in the function.

Comment: @RonakShah, you're absolutely right! I hadn't thought that it could be so easy. Do you have an explanation for why calling `v` without `get()` inside the wrap function wouldn't get me the value of the variable?

Comment: `ddply(df,v, summarize, mean = mean(b), var = var(b))` inside `sumfun` works ,  the dot `.` function defined in `plyr` is used a collect all  quoted variables for later evaluation, see `?plyr::.` and [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plyr` package and its `ddply` function are kind of outdated and evolved into the `dplyr`, `tidyr` and similar packages (referenced as `tidyverse`).

```
# library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
```

What you are trying to accomplish can be translated like this:

```
sample_df %>% 
    group_by(a) %>% 
    summarize(mean = mean(b), var = var(b))
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#       a  mean   var
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     0
# 2     2     2     0
# 3     3     1     0
```

And, for the function approach:

```
sumfun <- function(df, v) {
    df %>% 
        group_by_(v) %>% 
        summarize(mean = mean(b), var = var(b))
}

sumfun(sample_df, 'a')
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#       a  mean   var
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     0
# 2     2     2     0
# 3     3     1     0
```

Note the final `_` in `group_by_` present in function needed to do standard evaluation. See `vignette("nse")` for details.

Comment: I haven't quite transitioned to using the [pipe](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html) and pipe operator (`%>%`) yet. However, in this case readability seems to better with the pipe.